# Cannot see the DbContext from another project in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a web api project "Reactivities" and another project "Persisitence" to place my DbContext. When I try to use my add-migration in the Reactivities, using this syntax in the console `add-migration InitalCreate -Context .\Persistence` I get this error:

`No DbContext named '.\Persistence' was found.`

Even if I use `add-migration InitialCreate -Context .\Persistence\DataContext` still I get the same error,

This is in my startup class in Reactivities

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: at the top of the console window there is a combobox with all projects listed did you select the one that contains said context?

Comment: are you tried change selected project to Persistence in package manager console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do migration work in a project that instantiates the dbcontext, in my case I have created a dbmigrator project with a class that inherits the 
`IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<T>`
where T is the dbcontext type.

This allows me to have a project that has the dbcontexts, a project that works with migrations and a project that uses the dbcontexts independently of each other.

This guide shows you how to use the interface i mentioned:
https://codingblast.com/entityframework-core-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/

Comment: it is not mentioned that it has more than one dbcontex

Comment: no but the essential part is that to work with migrations, the target project has to be able to instantiate. if "Persisitence" cannot instantiate the dbcontext maybe because it does not have the settings or any other code than the definition, you can add a class that implements the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<T> to that project and tell it the settings and that will allow you to use migrations with that project even if the project does not "use" the dbcontext for anything.

Comment: Also, if he were to add migrations targeting the Reactivities project, then the migrations would be added in the Reactivities project which kind of defeats the purpose of removing the dbcontext from that project in the first place.